# CBOR encoding issue on format of keys

Tags: javascript, json, cbor

On javascript (not using node), I am facing different results when CBOR encoding using library (https://github.com/paroga/cbor-js) and when using CBOR online (https://cbor.me/). Note that even using a more recent CBOR library, result is identical.

For instance setting an object such as :

```
const initial = { 1: "John", "-2": 456 };
```

Encoding using CBOR online gives : a201644a6f686e622d321901c8. Details are :

```
A2             # map(2)
   01          # unsigned(1)
   64          # text(4)
      4A6F686E # "John"
   62          # text(2)
      2D32     # "-2"
   19 01C8     # unsigned(456)
```

Now encoding using CBOR library on javascript gives a different result : a26131644a6f686e622d321901c8

When decoding this above Hexadecimal on CBOR online, I got : {"1": "John", "-2": 456}. Result is almost identical than the constant 'initial' except that key 1 now appears with a quote (").

CBOR online re-formats my hexadecimal value to a more 'readable' view :

```
A2             # map(2)
   61          # text(1)
      31       # "1"
   64          # text(4)
      4A6F686E # "John"
   62          # text(2)
      2D32     # "-2"
   19 01C8     # unsigned(456)
```

See below my Javascript code :

```
    //convert an array of bytes (as 8 bits) to string of Hex. ensure that Hex value are not return with 1 digit but 2 digits. ie '01' instead of '1'
    function toHexString(byteArray) {
      var s = '';
      byteArray.forEach(function(byte) {
        s += ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      });
      return s;
    }

    const initial = { 1: "John", "-2": 456 };
    
    var encoded = CBOR.encode(initial);
    var encodedHex = toHexString(Array.from(new Uint8Array(encoded)));
    console.log ( encodedHex );
```

I could manually replace specific hexadecimal values such as :

'61 31 64' replaced by '01 64'

But not fancy doing it as list could be important to cover all possible options.

Does someone have a workaround as I need my result to be 'a201644a6f686e622d321901c8' and not 'a26131644a6f686e622d321901c8' ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Object keys in Javascript

The [CBOR specification, section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8949#map-keys) says:

> In applications that need to interwork with JSON-based applications, conversion is simplified by limiting keys to text strings only

And indeed, the `cbor-js` package uses the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method [here](https://github.com/paroga/cbor-js/blob/65dc49611107db83aff8308a6b381f4d7933824b/cbor.js#L162), which returns all keys as strings. Javascript does not distinguish between numbers and their string values and treats `{'1':1, 1:2}` as `{'1':2}` (whereas [cbor.me](https://cbor.me/?diag=%7B%271%27:%201,%201:%202%7D) treats this as a map with two entries).

#### Solution with a modified `cbor-js`

Your example suggests that you want *non-negative* numeric keys treated as numeric by CBOR. This can be achieved with the following patch on the [`cbor-js`](https://github.com/paroga/cbor-js) source code:

```
diff --git a/cbor.js b/cbor.js
--- a/cbor.js
+++ b/cbor.js
@@ -164,7 +164,10 @@ function encode(value) {
           writeTypeAndLength(5, length);
           for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
             var key = keys[i];
-            encodeItem(key);
+            if (isNaN(key) || Number(key) < 0)
+              encodeItem(key);
+            else
+              encodeItem(Number(key));
             encodeItem(value[key]);
           }
         }
```

With this change, Node.js gives me

```
> Buffer.from(cbor.encode({1:'John','-2':456})).toString('hex'))
'a201644a6f686e622d321901c8'
```

Or you could even treat negative numeric keys as numeric by leaving out the  `|| Number(key) < 0` in the patch above. This gives

```
> Buffer.from(cbor.encode({1:'John','-2':456})).toString('hex'))
'a201644a6f686e211901c8'
A2             # map(2)
   01          # unsigned(1)
   64          # text(4)
      4A6F686E # "John"
   21          # negative(1)
   19 01C8     # unsigned(456)
```

#### Solution with `cbor`

Unlike `cbor-js`, the [`cbor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cbor) package allows you to encode a Javascript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which distinguishes numeric from string keys:

```
> Buffer.from(cbor.encode(new Map().set(1,'John').set(-2,456))).toString('hex')
'a201644a6f686e211901c8'
```