# cbor encoding dictionary with int key(s) turn to string key(s) on the server side

Tags: javascript, cbor

```
# client side code:
import {encode, decode} from "cbor-js"
const data = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: :3}
const encoding = encode(data)
```

after sending the encoded data into the server (python) and decoding it I am receiving:

```
data = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}
```

instead of :

```
data = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was to modify the `cbor-js` lib so it'll also handle a `Map` type

encodeItem function:

```
else if (value instanceof Map){
  var keys = Array.from(value.keys());
  length = keys.length;
  writeTypeAndLength(5, length);
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    var key = keys[i];
    encodeItem(key);
    encodeItem(value.get(key));
  }
}
```

decodeItem addition:

```
case 5:
   function isStringType(val) {
      return typeof val === "string"
   }
   var retObject = new Map();
   for (i = 0; i < length || length < 0 && !readBreak(); ++i) {
       var key = decodeItem();
       retObject.set(key, decodeItem())
   }
   const allKeysAreStrings = Array.from(retObject.keys()).every(isStringType)
   if (allKeysAreStrings){
       retObject = Object.fromEntries(retObject)
   }
   return retObject;
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70395955/16462950

Comment: I saw it - it doesn't help - the cbor library encoding cannot be read on my server for some reason